# Assigning arrays with implicit loops

Tags: arrays, fortran

I want to write something like :

```
b=0e0
do j=1,n
   b(j,j) = f(x)*real(j)
end do
```

in an impicit way like, say

```
b=0e0
(b(j,j)=f(x)*real(j),j=1,n)
```

which isn't working. If the r.h.s. of the expression doesn't depend on j, I can of course do this:

```
b=0e0
c([(k,k=1,n*n,n+1)])=f(x)
b=reshape(c,shape(b))
```

but I'd love to have a more elegant and flexible one lined way, like a FORALL statement, e.g.

```
b=0e0
FORALL (j=1:n) b(j,j)=f(x)*real(j)
```

, but this is unfortunately a bit too restricted for the case where I need it. For the purpose of initialization there is something called DATA statement, which so far also didn't help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You've shown that you are familiar with the usual ways of initialising array sections (`forall`, implied do loops, section notation (such as `1:n:2`)).  Then you note that *this is unfortunately a bit too restricted for the case where I need it* but don't tell us what that case is.  How do you expect anyone to help without revealing what you really want to do ?  Note that if you have an up-to-date compiler `do concurrent` is generally preferable to `forall`.

Comment: Yes of course I tried a lot of ways before asking here. But as you see, none of them (besides the ordinary do loop) is working. I really love the FORALL statement. But f(x) in my case depends on lapack. This routines aren't defined PURE. I found LAPACK95 on netlib and intel also seems to provide something similar. I'll try this after I found out how. Anyhow you are right, it seems that DO CONCURRENT does what I want, but the intel and gnu compilers only support the construct but not the statement (which is fine, but a bit less readable) and the PGI compiler doesn't seem to support it at all.

Comment: What do you mean by "it seems that DO CONCURRENT does what I want, but the intel and gnu compilers only support the construct but not the statement"? DO CONCURRENT is only a block construct - there is no FORALL-statement-like form. I'll note that FORALL is likely to be deprecated in the next standard.

Comment: Hey, "it seems" means that I couldn't find it but I'm not yet sure about it's existance. Still I'm wondering if there is any tunable one lined command to for my example, like the implicite loop, which is nicely working together with a write statement but not (that I know) for assigning data.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a subroutine that sets the diagonal of a matrix to a vector, as shown below.

```
program xdiag
implicit none
integer, parameter :: n = 3
real :: xmat(n,n) = 0.0
integer :: i
call set_diag([1.0,4.0,9.0],xmat)
do i=1,n
   print*,xmat(i,:)
end do
contains
subroutine set_diag(diag,xmat)
real, intent(in)     :: diag(:)
real, intent(in out) :: xmat(:,:)
integer              :: i,n
n = size(diag)
if (any(shape(xmat) /= n)) then
   print*,"in set_diag, size(diag) =",size(diag)," shape(xmat)=",shape(xmat)," should all be equal, STOPPING"
   stop
end if
forall (i=1:n) xmat(i,i) = diag(i)
end subroutine set_diag
end program xdiag
! output:
! 1. 0. 0.
! 0. 4. 0.
! 0. 0. 9.
```